# How to fix Joi error on DynamoDB TypeError: child.schema._getLabel is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, joi, vogels

I have a schema in dynamodb as shown below, I am using Joi, Vogels and NodeJS

```js
schema: {
email: Joi.string().email(),
  item: Joi.array().items(Joi.object().keys({
    a: Vogels.types.uuid(),
    b: Joi.string(),
    c: Joi.string(),
    d: Joi.string().email()
 }))
```

I am trying to insert the following data in the table

```js
var Obj = {
    email: 'a@b.com',
    item: [{
        b: 'data',
        c: 'some-data',
        d: 'b@c.com'
    }]
};
```

I am using the below nodejs code to insert the data to table

```js
Model.create(Obj, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        return cb(err);
    } else {
    console.log(data);
    return cb(null,data);
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error

```js
errors.push(this.createError('object.child', { key, child: child.schema._getLabel(key), reason: result.errors }, localState, options));

TypeError: child.schema._getLabel is not a function
```

Can someone help me out or explain , why i am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: You're missing a bracket at the end of your schema in the first snippet of code.

Comment: @PatrickMotard The code for schema was just for representational purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the UUID field (i.e. attribute 'a'). I understand that vogels is supposed to generate the UUID automatically. However, there is no working example of automatic UUID value generation for non-key attributes though as per the document it should generate. It should work OK if you define a UUID for key attributes.

The below solution is a workaround to generate the UUID and assign the value to attribute 'a'.

**1) Install the node-uuid module**

```
node install node-uuid
```

**2) Add the requires:-**

```
var nodeUUID = require('node-uuid');
```

**3) Change the object as mentioned below:-**

```
var Obj = {
    email : 'abc@b.com',
    item : [ {
        a : nodeUUID.v1(),
        b : 'data',
        c : 'some-data',
        d : 'b@c.com'
    } ]
};
```

You should be able to insert an item successfully. I have tested it and works ok.